# Kivy search box with suggestion?

Tags: kivy

I am beginner to kivy so seniors pls help me how we can bind textinput box to suggestion so that user and touch and select the suggestions?so user can touch(suggestion) ,select and open(suggestion)in Label.I have a long multi text file so i want to open it by chapter or by title.thanks a million for your help[getting suggestion from search bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WY6BI.jpg)
[opening suggestion keyword(text)to new screen/Label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yU1n.jpg)

Comment: Apologies, but I'm having a very hard time understanding what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

it is easier to understand your questions, when you write it more specific and adding the code, e.g. of the TextInput etc.

However, if you want suggestions pop up while the user is typing anything into the TextInput: use the `on_text' method. it gets called when the text is changing.

e.g.

```
class SearchBar(TextInput):
    def on_text(self, widget, value):
        #value is the currently typed text
        #call function that gets the suggestsions based on the typed text
        # use add_widget() function to create Widgets into the layout for the suggestisons....
        pass
```